# Как обратно получить объект из строки созданной при помощи obj.toString()?

Tags: java, serializable, сериализация

Я могу записать объект в файл, приведя его к строке:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        User defaultUser = new User(1, "Ivan", "Ivanovich", "Ivanov", null, 27);
        saveToFile("users.txt", defaultUser.toString());
    }
```

Содержимое *user.txt*:

```
com.petproject.me.User@5f184fc6
```

Можно ли каким-то способом из такой строки получить обратно объект типа User?

Comment: Нет, нельзя. :(

Comment: Из такой нельзя никак:) Метод `toString` `по умолчанию` выдаёт `адрес` объекта, но не его `содержимое`. И восстановить из такой строки ничего невозможно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, нельзя.

```
saveToFile("users.txt", new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(defaultUser));
```

Answer (score 2):

Как уже сказали выше, так сделать нельзя (так как вы просто сохранили строковое представление объекта (его легко можно изменить переопределив метод `ToString()`)). Для сохранения и чтения объектов советую почитать про `Сериализация и десериализация в Java`